# Software Sources not accessible from Discover

Tags: kubuntu, software-sources, 22.04, discover-software-center

Updated to Kubuntu 22.04 today and i am facing a problem with Software Sources in Discover.

I am able to install and remove programs using discover.

[image]

My password is not being accepted.  It was working properly in 21.10.  Screen Shots are given below.

[image: Initial Password Screen]

When I enter the password it gives me this screen
[image]

Found a way out by using the terminal and a `sudo software-properties-kde` and it worked.  But not working from Discover.

Can someone help in rectifying this error.  Thanks in advance.

Regards,
Sriram

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To reach that dialog, we can go to the command line and execute `sudo -i software-properties-qt`.

Additional information:

- The `-i` of `sudo -i` is [important](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/35338/su-vs-sudo-s-vs-sudo-i-vs-sudo-bash) in order to [avoid some problems](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/98531/difference-between-sudo-i-and-sudo-su).
- We can also execute `sudo -i software-properties-kde` [if it's available](https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=425073#c6).
- There are bug reports about it ([1](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/kdesu/+bug/1965439), [2](https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=452532)).

Comment: what happened to tools like kdesudo, gksudo, kdesu etc ?

Answer (score 7):

This should be reported as a bug.

Related to the problem that [`KDE su` is used](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/694339/341192) instead of the KDE Agent.

The problem is with the desktop-launcher file (`/usr/share/applications/software-properties-qt.desktop`), which contains the line

```
X-KDE-SubstituteUID=true
```

Open that in Kate and remove that line or change it to `false`.

In my case the Software Sources would still not open: it needed a further change of the `Exec` line, like so:

```
Exec=pkexec env DISPLAY=$DISPLAY XAUTHORITY=$XAUTHORITY software-properties-qt
```

In order to be able to find the Software Sources directly in the Application launchers without passing through Discover we need to change the line `NoDisplay=true` to `false`. In Tiled Menu:

[image]

Comment: Thank you.  I have reported it as a bug in both KDE as well as Ubuntu Bugs.

Comment: @SriramRayadurg - Please click the v sign under the answer points to mark it as definitive

Comment: @SriramRayadurg Could you also add the link to the bug, so we can vote for it?

Comment: Thanks for the answer (I happen to have the same problem). Your adjustments do not seem to work for me though (I am trying to access software sources via muon).

Comment: @Bruni - Please post a separate question asking about exactly what it doesn't work, link it here for me, and I could help. Software Sources should be accessible as a separate "app launcher" too, as seen in image.

Comment: @cipricus Software-sources is accessible as a separate application (even without any adjustment to the .desktop file). However, it is not accessible via muon. I would rather not post a separate question. In fact I was posting a separate question, when I stumbled upon this one and the only difference was that I was using muon instead of discover and had one less screenshot..

Comment: @Bruni - Now I get it. But the Muon problem may be separate and thus worth a question.

Comment: @cipricus Indeed, it might. Though I just realized another problem with discover (not seeing sources except snap, flatpak and firmware). Going to post this first.

Comment: @Bruni -  What I can notice on my system is that while my Discover triggers `software-properties-qt` and is depending on the settings in the corresponding desktop file, Muon relates to `usr/bin/software-properties-kde` and ignores setting in  desktop file from `usr/share/applications`.

Comment: good catch. Also I  had read somewhere (I know not a good quote) that `usr/bin/software-properties-kde` is deprecated.

Comment: @cipricus just in case you have an answer: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1405218/how-to-access-software-sources-repositories-from-discover-in-kde-22-04

Comment: @Bruni - it took me some time  to grasp your question :) Oddly, I see "Software Sources" *twice* where you have none listed!

Comment: "> SriramRayadurg, Could you also add the link to the bug, so we can vote for it?" @Bruni, we can see   https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/kdesu/+bug/1965439    and    https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=452532

Comment: As @cipricus writes above, this fixes the problem with Discover, but doesn't fix the problem with muon. In /usr/bin/software-properties-kde the test is specifically for uid=0, i.e. root, and I am too ignorant to risk changing anything there anything there. I don't understand Bruni's reference to "How to access software sources (repositories) from discover in KDE 22.04?" as it doesn't seem to apply to muon.  I am opening a new question for muon as suggested above.

Comment: This is a great solution, but I had to do the opposite of what is described here:
>>
In order to be able to find the Software Sources directly in the Application launchers without passing through Discover we need to change the line NoDisplay=false to true. 
<<
To access Software Sources directly, I had to change "NoDisplay" from "true" to "false".

Comment: @RB - Oh sorry, that was an error in my post! Obviously, in order to "display" the thing, the "NoDisplay" has to be set to "false"!

Answer (score 0):

In a pinch, from within settings you could go to the driver manager section.
It would open the appropriate window you need. "Software Sources"
Then you can just pick the tab needed to select your desired input.
in the event you don't feel comfortable manipulating configuration files.