# How to access software sources (repositories) from discover in KDE 22.04?

Tags: kubuntu, software-center

I cannot seem to find a link to software sources in discover after the update to Kubuntu 22.04.Also only firmare, snap and flatpak are displayed as sources.
[image]

Comment: Do you have `software-properties-qt` installed in your system? That's the program the `software sources`-button opens on my system.

Comment: What happens if you select "Add source"?

Comment: After creating a new desktop file in `usr/share/applications` called `software-properties-kde` (beside the `software-properties-qt` already present - for the purpose of fixing a Muon problem discussed in comments under [here](https://askubuntu.com/q/1404500/925128)), on my system I have 2 "Software Sources"in Discover, which confirms that those buttons are links to desktop files in `usr/share/applications`. Corresponding tools like `software-properties-qt` need to be installed. Do you have that installed? Do you have the file `/usr/share/applications/software-properties-qt.desktop`?

Comment: I have `software-properties-qt` installed, though not `software-properties-kde` installed.

Comment: I also am unable to install software-properties-kde due to dependency issues.

Comment: @cipricus I have the file /usr/share/applications/software-properties-qt.desktop and I have edited it as suggested in the comments to the other question. Also: when I press add source I can add an additional flatpak repo....

Comment: `software-properties-qt` is what you need and what you should have accessible from Discover. If there is no other way, simply make it accessible separately as indicated under the other Q.

Comment: @cipricus I have it installed and it is accessible separately (so I do not have a real usability problem). Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Same issue here, this solved it for me:

Run Discover, go to the settings page, then view your `journalctl` (run `journalctl` in console and hit the <kbd>End</kbd> key to jump down).

That showed an error for an improperly formatted file in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/` from a release upgrade. After removing the broken source, Discovery shows the sources now.

Comment: Interesting. Though, my sources.list.d seems fine (no error messages in journalctl and no error messages when running apt-get update.