# Post upgrade to Ubuntu Studio 22.04, I am now denied access to "Software and Updates"

Tags: upgrade, 22.04, update-manager, groups

I have two computers running Ubuntu Studio 22.04, which were each just recently upgraded from 21.10. We'll call them, simply, my "gaming PC" and my [non-gaming] "laptop". And I've noticed an interesting and troubling side-effect of running the upgrade: on both devices, post-upgrade, I am no longer able to access "Software and Upgrades".

I first discovered the issue on my laptop, which was upgraded to 22.04 first - about a week or two ago. Knowing that certain 3rd party repositories are disabled during the upgrade, I wished to go to "Software and Updates" to check to see if they needed re-enabled. Earlier tonight, I upgraded the gaming PC to match. Prior to the upgrade, I entered "Software and Updates" just to make sure that I could - and I could.  Post upgrade, I now no longer can.

The error message is the same on both computers:

"Permission denied.
Possibly incorrect password, please try again.
On some systems, you need to be in a special group (often: wheel) to use this program.

Command: /usr/bin/software-properties-gtk"

So, naturally, I run "sudo nano /usr/bin/software-properties-gtk" to see what's inside the file. I see a number of things, but nothing that is obvious to a rookie like me on where to fix the issue with access. I don't think it's a superuser problem because any sudo command I run in terminal works just fine.

If you need me to pastebin the contents of the nano file, just let me know. Otherwise, I am very eager to receive your advice and guidance on this, because I want to make sure I can access this very important program! And in case it's helpful information, the exact command I ran to perform the upgrade was simply "sudo do-release-upgrade". I know some people follow that base command up with things like "-c" or "-d" or whatever. I did none of that, just used the base command - like I have for every upgrade since making Ubuntu Studio my "daily driver" OS back at 19.04.

Beyond this, the only things I've noticed is that transparencies and blurs are not as transparent as they used to be on either device. And on many of my apps on the gaming PC, such as Chrome and Steam, the transparencies are just absent completely. That part I am reasonably certain I will be able to figure out on my own (or at least successfully Google search my way through). It feels like a situation I've run into (and resolved) in the past. I just can't recall what precisely that resolution was. But if you're handing out advice already, I suppose I'll be happy to take your advice here as well. ;-)

Comment: i encountered the same problem - after the update i can not access software-sources from the application menu.
from the commandline `sudo software-properties-kde`,  `software-properties-qt` and also `sudo software-properties-gtk` is working. so it seems it has to do with the calling...

Answer (score 0):

after some searching [i found](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/slackware-14/gui-version-of-sudo-for-kde-4175648632/#post5964067) that for me with

```
pkexec env DISPLAY=$DISPLAY XAUTHORITY=$XAUTHORITY software-properties-qt
```

as command in the menu config it is working as expected:
it first shows the password request and on success opens the software-sources window.

---

if you have only the `software-properties-qt` line and no *run as other user* selected it opens a screen saying:

> Please run this software with administrative rights. To do so, run this program with lxqt-sudo or pkexec.

only `pkexec software-properties-qt` does not work.
i think the target program does not get the correct display and user or so...

with the *DISPLAY XAUTHORITY* enviroments set it is working.

Comment: just found another solution: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1404500/software-sources-not-accessible-from-discover

Comment: UPDATE: Just upgraded from 22.04 to 22.10 and it appears to be resolved in the new release! So, hooray! :-)